# Use PHP to echo whats inside div tags

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I dont know what to research or where to start here.

What im trying to do is use PHP to read an HTML Page and pull out the raw text contained inside a div

the div is this

```
 <div class="thingy">
  test
 </div>
```

When the php is executed, I want it to echo

```
Test
```

Is there an easy snippet for this, or can someone post a small script?

Edit: the html page with the Div is on another webpage.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in php, PHP is a server side language, HTML is client side and you can easily do this by using javascript.

Comment: try this. preg_match_all('/<div class="thingy">(.*)<\/div>/isU',$htmlContent,$text_array);

Comment: @PankajKhairnar: He can't do this using JS if he's scraping a page.

Comment: $url    = "page url";
$htmlContent = file_get_contents($url); you grab the data using file_get_contents right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse your html you can use it like

```
<?php
 $str = '<div class="thingy">test</div>';
 echo strip_tags($str);//OUTPUT : test
?>
```

As your html is on other webpage, start output buffering include that file in your main php script, do all manipulation on it to get the content.

Comment: How would I do this, if the div is on a seperate html page on another url.

Comment: then it is always better to use javascript for parsing your html on client side if your want to do like this way I can answer your question using javascript method

Comment: I will accept java script IF you can post a Way to scrape the div off the html page that is not local to the file being executed.

Comment: i'll create a example in html and post as a answer, give me some time

Comment: Like i Said... The DIV isnt on the same page, I want to scrape the page with the div, and then read it... also where did ThingyID come from? thats not in the page.

Comment: got it you can include your html start output buffering get the data from buffer and read it as html in php, now do whatever manipulation you want to do in that file

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking to do is parse HTML.  Use the DOM module that comes with PHP to do this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

You do NOT want to try to do this with regular expressions.

If you want to remove ALL the HTML tags from a document, use the PHP `strip_tags()` function: https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: i would go fo simpleXML not DOM as it is easier. Tough it depends on input

Answer (score 2):

While this could possibly be done using regex, I would recommend using a DOM parser. My reccommendation goes to [SimpleHTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Using it, here's how you would do what you want

```
$string = "<div class=\"thingy\">test</div>";
$html = str_get_html($string); // create the DOM object
$div = $html->find('div[class=thingy]', 0); // find the first div with a class of 'thingy'
echo $div->plaintext(); // echo the text contents
```